# jquery : How to bind change event when the input is not from the user

Tags: jquery

I have an input field named DateFrom. Right next to it it's an icon that shows the calendar where the user selects a date. When a user selects a date, the DateFrom is being filled by this value.

I need to bind a "change" event on the DateFrom in order to do some calculation. I wasn't lucky using change or focusout. The following didn't work either:

```
$('#datefrom').change(function () {
    console.log("AutoChange");
 }
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you put the code you have showing both this input fields and the date,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing value of an input programmatically doesn't trigger `change` event. You have to trigger the event yourself. Since you are using jQuery you can use it's `.trigger()` or `.change()` method.

```
$('input[name="DateFrom"]').val(newVal).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thank you. Where should trigger bind to? DateFrom ?

Comment: @kristos The trigger method just triggers the event, in this case for `'input[name="DateFrom"]'` element, you should listen to `change` event before triggering the event as you are doing it currently. `$('input[name="DateFrom"]').on('change', handler)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also trigger "change" event simply doing:

```
$('#datefrom').change();
```